# Forwarding JWT in Envoy gateway

Tags: .net, docker, jwt, envoyproxy

I have a .NET microservice container that uses JWT authorization to control access. I placed this container behind an Envoy gateway that's configured as such:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - safe_regex:
                    google_re2: {}
                    regex: \*
                allow_methods: "GET, POST, DELETE"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/api/v2/PublishDatabase"
                route:
                  cluster: publish-database
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8443
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - safe_regex:
                    google_re2: {}
                    regex: \*
                allow_methods: "GET, POST, DELETE"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/api/v2/PublishDatabase"
                route:
                  cluster: publish-database
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication
              forward: true
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "./https.crt"
              private_key:
                filename: "./key.pem"

  clusters:
  - name: publish-database
    connect_timeout: 15s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: publish-database
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: publishdatabase
                port_value: 80
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
```

However, Envoy completely swallows the bearer token in the authorization header. I've searched through the documentation, and the only thing I found was to forward the JWT after it validates it within Envoy, and I really just want to forward it to the container.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error with your config, but my application defined in the `clusters` part got the headers correctly forwarded. I just removed the `forward: true` in your `jwt_authn` filter config because otherwise the config was not valid (I'm using envoy v1.21.0). What version of envoy are you using ? Could you try without the `forward: true` ?

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need the `http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication` filter if you just want to validate the JWT in your application, not in Envoy.

Comment: This is my bad, it was erroring on CORS preflight and I didn't notice, but when I clicked through it gave me a invalid token exception. I cleared out the CORS and JwtAuthentication and used the setup I had in the container and it works fine. Thanks!